# Change /usr/lib to /usr/lib32 for eclipse to look for *.so files

Tags: 64-bit, eclipse, 32-bit

I am trying to run eclipse and I am getting:

> /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
>   Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so

I already found out that it is because this library is 64bits. I have found 32bit version of it and putted in subdirectory of /usr/lib32 but eclipse do not want to look for it there.
How can I make it to look for libraries in /usr/lib32?

Comment: How did you install `eclipse`? If you installed `eclipse` through the package manager, this should not be happening.

Comment: This should not even happen if eclipse has been downloaded from eclipse.org :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run 32-bit eclipse (supposedly downloaded from eclipse.org, because Ubuntu package manager wouldn't let you do that) on 64-bit Ubuntu. While theoretically it *may* be possible to make this work, the easiest would be either to install eclipse using Ubuntu Software Center, or, if you have reasons to do so, download the proper installer from from eclipse.org

Their website has separate downloads for 32-bit and 64-bit Linux. You need the 64-bit one.